# Trying to use a method from a model's struct with a view's onAppear

Tags: swift, swiftui, methods

I am trying to run a function which fills in an array with objects. I want this to run whenever a certain view appears, so that the array is always updated and the view is displaying the right information.

I created the function in the appropriate struct, made it mutating and public. I also tried making the struct itself public. Whenever I try to call the function after the body of the view with the onAppear, I get an "expected declaration" error. And when I enter in the function I get a message saying "this method is defined on * and may not be available in this context. Thank you for any help, the relevant code is below!

The function call with onAppear:

```
struct FriendsView: View {

    var allFriends: [Friend] = FriendsList.allFriends
    var favoriteFriends: [Friend] = FriendsList.favoriteFriends
    var nonFavFriends: [Friend] = FriendsList.nonFavFriends

    var body: some View {

... 

}
    .onAppear(perform: FriendsList.fillNonFavFriends())
```

The function itself in the struct:

```
public struct FriendsList {

    mutating func fillNonFavFriends() {
        for Friend in allFriendsLocal {
            if favoriteFriendsLocal.contains(Friend) {
            
            } else {
                nonFavFriendsLocal.append(Friend)
            }
        }
        FriendsList.nonFavFriends = nonFavFriendsLocal
    }
```

}

Comment: You'd need to manage your data in some way that is compatible with SwiftUI updates. `@State`, `ObservableObject`, or the new `Observation` framework are all options. In regards to the latter: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this, but the issue comes mixing up [instance methods](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/methods/#Instance-Methods) and [type methods](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/methods/). Here are two options to fix this:

**Method 1:** Declare an instance of `FriendsList` in `FriendsView` and call the methods from the instance.

Instance methods belong to instances of structs/classes. An example of this is calling `"Hello!".lowercased()`, since the method is called on an **instance** of a `String`.

You would need to populate your `FriendsView` with an **instance** of `FriendsList`, which would look like this:

```
struct FriendsView: View {
    @State var friendsList = FriendsList()

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
    .onAppear(perform: friendsList.fillNonFavFriends())
}
```

---

**Method 2:** Declare the function as a [type method](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/methods/), also known as a static method.

Static methods belong to types, not instances, and thus are called on the type itself. An example of this is calling `Double.pi` to get the value of pi. Note how we don't need to create an object to call this method, we simple reference the `Double` type.

You use the `static` keyword to declare static methods. Here's how it would work in your example:

```
static func fillNonFavFriends() {
    ...
}
```

```
.onAppear(perform: FriendsList.fillNonFavFriends())
```